# Boto S3 delete_keys method indicating non-existent keys as being deleted

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I'm running into the following issue using boto's delete_keys() command in s3.

This is my test scenario:

```
import boto

conn = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = conn.get_bucket('mybucket')

key1 = boto.s3.key.Key('bucket','not_a_real_key1')
key2 = boto.s3.key.Key('bucket','not_a_real_key2')

result_set = bucket.delete_keys([key1,key2])

#the following should not print anything
for v in result_set.deleted:
  print v

#the following should return the two keys
for v in result_set.errors:
  print v
```

As per the commented lines, since the two keys don't exist I'd assume they'd be marked as errors and not as deleted.

Is this standard behavior? I'd rather not use the Key.exists() method as I'm iterating through a large number of keys and this would be inefficient.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is expected behavior for S3.  When you delete a nonexistent key, either individually or in a bulk delete operation, any keys that don't exist are treated as deleted keys and no error is returned.

Comment: To clarify, the S3 REST API exhibits this behavior, so it impacts all client libraries -- deleting an object returns the same success response even when there's no such object.  Presumably,  because no matter how many times you delete an object, it's still equally gone, whether or not it ever existed.  S3's eventual consistency on object deletion may make this behavior necessary, since it's possible (but unlikely) that you could fetch an object after deleting it for a short time, leading you to attempt to delete it again, by which time, the first delete might have become consistently visible.